# What is the average number of cards dealt until the ace of spades turns up?

Tags: probability

Cards are drawn from a pack until the ace of spades turns up. Then on an average, number of cards dealt is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 52 possible outcomes, each equally likely (having a chance of $\frac{1}{52}$ to happen). The expected number of cards dealt is:

$$\frac{1}{52} \sum_{i=1}^{52}i = \frac{1}{52}\frac{52\cdot53}{2} = 26.5$$

A more intuitive way to arrive at the same result is to realize that you'll *always* deal the ace of spades, and on average, exactly *half* of the other 51 cards. That leads to $1 + \frac{51}{2} = 26.5$.